# Diablo 3 RoS Damage model

Tags: diablo-iii

Benchmarking and dmg-prediction gear/spec in D3 is quite difficult... my question is in this "field"...

I would like to know how the damage model works regarding the "+ Holy/Fire/Lightning %dmg" and the "+ X% (skill name here) dmg"... consider the following scenario: I have a char that casts a fireball (fire dmg) and it hits for 100 dmg. so, consider `Ring A` a ring that only has 1 stat and that stat is **+ 10% fire dmg** and `Ring B` gives **+ 15% fireball dmg**

1. If I use Ring A (gives **10%** fire dmg,) the fireball will hit for 110?
2. If I use Ring B (that gives **15%** fireball dmg) the fireball will hit for 115?
3. If I use Ring A and B the fireball will hit for 110, 115, 125, 126.5?
4. If I crit for 2x, while using only Ring A the value of the hit will be `(100*2)+10%`(220) or `(100*2)+(10%*2)`(240)?

Comment: I don't know for sure, so this is going in the comments. Scenario 1 and 2 are correct. Scenario 3 I believe would be 125 as I think +skill damage is added together.  Critting for 2x SHOULD be 250 because you take the base (125) and then multiply by 2.  The only times where the values multiply differently I think is when you have +Elite damage, skill/elemental damage, and % damage debuffs (Mantra of Conviction for instance).  Once again, I could be wrong about how the damage sources are added/multiplied together.

Comment: This spreadsheet is the best compendium on how the damage calculation happens: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Avxzyy5pHlsZdDZoVzNQeVl3XzA3bExpdk5yTVdaV1E

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know from testing and reading the Diablo 3 forums: there are several groups of buffs and each group is multiplicative with the other groups (and thus a separate multiplier). Check out [this thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058607023) for more information on multipliers.

To answer your specific question using the terminology from the linked thread:

1. The `+10% fire damage` from `Ring A` falls in Class B
2. The `+15% fireball damage` from `Ring B` falls in Class A3.

Assuming you're *only* wearing `Ring A`, then your 100 damage fireball with Fire element will hit for 100 * 1.1 = 110 damage.

Assuming you're *only* wearing `Ring B`, then your 100 damage fireball, regardless of element, will hit for 100 * 1.15 = 115 damage.

Assuming you're *only* wearing `Ring A` and `Ring B` and no other modifiying equipment, then your 100 damage fireball with Fire element will hit for 100 * 1.1 * 1.15 = 126.5 damage, which will be rounded to 127.

When you crit for 100% damage, it will do 100 * 1.1 * 1.15 * 2 = 253 damage.